# CORS problem with VueJS using axios or vue-resource

Tags: vue.js, caching, cors

I'm working on a SPA website using VueJS, i have a problem when vue-ressource performs http requests to an external API.

here is an example of console output :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backoffice.warmango.fr/api/v1/catalog/products/7424' from origin 'https://sandbox.warmango.fr' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://v3.warmango.dev' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

But when I open the console (with Disable cache ckecked) 
the problem disappears and I can navigate normally...

It is very frustrating, is there a cache problem with VueJS ?

Comment: You might try having that server send back a 'Vary: Origin' response header

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify `crossdomain` to true?

```
axios.get(url, { crossdomain: true })
```

Source : https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/853#issuecomment-322954804